# Deploy docker image of react app to Elastic beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to deploy my create-react-app to elastic bean stalk with docker
I have setup codepipeline with codebuild and elastic beanstalk.

I am getting this error

```
Stop running the command. Error: Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage  
# Create app directory  
# RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app  
# WORKDIR /usr/src/app  
  
WORKDIR /app  
  
  
# # fix npm private module  
# ARG NPM_TOKEN  
# COPY .npmrc /app/  
#COPY package.json package.json  
  
COPY package*.json /app/ 
COPY Dockerrun.aws.json /app/  
RUN npm install  
COPY ./ /app/  
# RUN CI=true npm test  
RUN npm run build  
  
# FROM nginx:1.15  
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine   
  
# Install app dependencies  
  
# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx  
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html  
# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend  
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  
  
RUN ls   
EXPOSE 80
```

I also have a Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "3",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "something.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/subscribili:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

my buildspec.yml file looks like this

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - REPOSITORY_URI=something.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/subscribili
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - printf '[{"name":"nginx","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

I am sure there is some issue with buildspec file but I am just not sure what.

I have read all the documentation still couldn't figure out how to write the buildspec file Docker.
Is there anything I am missing?

[image]

Comment: You have oly one artifact `imagedefinitions.json`? What about everything else, namely  the files from the error message?

Comment: @Marcin What all needs to be there?

Comment: Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json these 2 files need to be in the same directory where the command "COPY Dockerrun.aws.json /app/ " is running.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json these 2 files need to be in the same directory where the command "COPY Dockerrun.aws.json /app/ " is running. make sure these files exists in that directory and this error should disappear

Comment: These files exists. Let me add screenshot of my folder structure.

Comment: I think "Dockerrun.aws.json" file is allowed only in zip. Can you try that? Also you can checkout this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648966/return-code-1-output-dockerfile-and-dockerrun-aws-json-are-both-missing-abort Maybe that will help

Comment: How do add that in the zip?
I am not zipping it anywhere Do i have to?
And if yes what do i need to zip I have created a docker image already and pushed it to ecr repository so I was hoping elastic beanstalk will pick it from there.

Answer (score 0):

"eb deploy" command creates a zip file from your code. However, to make it as small as possible, it only takes the file that are commited to git. So, if you did not commit Dockerfile and Dockerrun file, these two files won't be included in the zip.

If you do not want it to behave like this, you can add .ebignore file to your projects root directory. This files commands are the same as the gitignore file; you can copy everything from gitignore to ebignore. If there is a .ebignore, cli will not check if the project is commited to a source control.

Now to check what is included in zip file, watch the .elasticbeanstalk folder after "eb deploy" command. When the zip is prepared, copy it immediately and paste to another folder. Note: the original zip file will be removed after the cli upload that.